# The Executable was signed with invalid entilements - Distribution Profile -Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I'm getting the following error when I create a Distribution Provisioning Profile and try to run to the device
"The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file do not match those specified in your provisioning profile. (0xE8008016)."

I didn't find any issue if I create Adhoc Distribution provisioning profile  and install in my device. But this happens only with Distribution Provisioning profile.Will this have any effect after submission to app store or while submitting to app store.?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install and run an app signed with a distribution profile. Those are for submitting only.

Comment: I want to know whether this is expected behaviour or not. For my previous applications when i try to do the same, I got an error stating that Not a valid Profile, but this is the first time I'm getting it when I try to run with Distribution profile.

Comment: It is expected behaviour. The app will submit without this being an issue.